# RasterLayer vs RasterStack

Tags: raster, r, stack, rasterstack

I have a few hundreds of .tiff files that I converted as a raster stack. However, when I tried reading the file, it is classified as a RasterLayer. I was expecting it to be a RasterStack. The functions that I would use to my usual raster stack won't work i.e. `subset()`. Also when I convert it `as.data.frame`, it only give me the xy coordinates and the value of the raster. Did I make a wrong decision of stacking my rasters? Any hints on how to break down my rasters layers?

```
Btw, my raster looks like this: 
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  414  bands)
dimensions : 605, 973, 588665  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 231.6564, 231.6564  (x, y)
extent     : 11267070, 11492472, 1355190, 1495342  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : /Users/manuel/UWThesis/RCodes/files/KTpostdam_evi.tif 
names      : KTpostdam_evi 
values     : -19030000, 79780000  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more information would prove useful to help answer your question. What language are you using, and what function are you using to import your data? I will base my answer on the assumption you are using `R` with the `raster` library and the `raster` function to import your `.tif` files. If you want your `tif` files to come in as a stack, use the `raster::stack()` fucntion.

```
library(raster)
stackTif <- stack(file.choose())
```

This will create a raster stack rather than a raster layer file.

Cheers